# Intuition for chains and cochains

Tags: integration, reference-request, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I'd like to get some "geometric," "physical," (or other form of) intuition for chains, cochains, and their relationship to integration on manifolds at an elementary level.  In particular, it would be nice to see some pictures and "physical" applications of these guys.

Anyone have any good references or other resources that might help?

Comment: Are you interested in a particular cohomology theory? (De Rham, singular, etc.) Also, what do you already know about manifolds? Providing more context would help in giving more suitable recommendations.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I don't know enough about cohomology to answer the first question, but I suspect I'd be interest in all of the above on some level.  I've worked through most of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, I've learned a decent amount of differential geometry in the context of general relativity and high energy physics, I'm comfortable with differential forms, covariant derivatives, etc. (although I imagine understanding semi-Riemannian geometry won't really help much here)

Comment: Have a look at [An introduction to manifolds](http://amzn.com/1441973990). It introduces the basics of smooth manifolds, integration on manifolds and De Rham cohomology. If this seems too basic, then perhaps [Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology](http://amzn.com/0387906134) is better suited. Hatcher's book is excellent but it doesn't cover integration on manifolds (or much manifold theory for the matter).

Comment: @AymanHourieh I actually have the first book; didn't think to look there.  What I'd really like to read is some sort of exposition devoted entirely to the intuition.  Perhaps something that does computations in the context of some physical applications of chains and cochains with lots of pictures etc.  I feel like someone somewhere must have written something like this.  Thanks for the references.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: IMO Differential forms in AT is a bit hardcore for a complete beginner, at least the latter chapters on spectral sequences.

Comment: @nik True. This is why I recommended "an introduction to manifolds" first as a gentle introduction to integration on manifolds and De Rham cohomology.

Comment: @joshphysics I interpreted intuition as mathematical intuition. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with books with physical intuition.

Answer (score 4):

Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* is excellent in this respect (intuition). It's also available for free on the author's home page: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the works by Alain Bossavit on this: he presents electromagnetism in terms of chains, cochains, and integration theory, and gives a very physical and intuitive, pictorial understanding of this topic. Moreover, he also uses it for numerical computations of electromagnetic problems, combined with a discretization of these objects. I recommend these works to start with:

- *Computational electromagnetism and geometry: building a finite-dimensional "Maxwell's house"* (2004) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242462763_Computational_electromagnetism_and_geometry_Building_a_finite-dimensional_Maxwell%27s_house (originally published in a journal 1999–2000);
- *Computational Electromagnetism: Variational Formulations, Complementarity, Edge Elements* (2nd ed., Academic Press 2004);
- *Discretization of electromagnetic problems: The "generalized finite differences" approach* (2005) https://doi.org/10.1016/S1570-8659(04)13002-0;
- *A uniform rationale for Whitney forms on various supporting shapes* (2010) https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matcom.2008.11.005.

You can check other works by the same author and the references in them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check this stuff out.